# Crosschecking Two Text Files with R

Tags: r, excel

I need help in initiating/writing an R script that can cross check one .txt file with another to find where there are multiple instances. I have an excel file with a list of miRNAs that I want to cross reference with another excel file that has a column that contains the same miRNA name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is it a text file or excel file you are importing? Without more details, file structure, or a reproducible example, it will be hard to help.

You can try:

```
# Get the correct package
install.packages('readxl')

df1 <- readxl::read_excel('[directory name][file name].xlsx')
df2 <- readxl::read_excel('[directory name][file name].xlsx')

# Creates a new variable flag if miRNA from your first dataset is in the second dataset
df1$is_in_df2 <- ifelse(df1$miRNA %in% df2$miRNA, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: I can import either format, I don't think it will matter. I currently have them in excel format. Basically, what I want to do is have the first file with just miR names cross check with another file that has multiple columns, and then indicate which gene is associated with the miR name.